# How can I write a makefile rule with dependencies that depend on parts of the target?

Tags: makefile

I want to write a rule that looks something like this:

```
A_vs_B.txt : A.txt B.txt
```

but a general rule. The problem is I can't have two %s (as far as I know). I was thinking of just making the target %.txt and then using string functions to parse out the A and B in the dependencies, but that will be fairly complicated. I'm wondering if there's a better way to write a rule like this.

Comment: How is `A_vs_B.txt` determined? Are there known pairs? Are they pairs in a sequence? In a pattern? Arbitrary?

Comment: They're pairs created from two variables I set when I run make. It's just four different targets that are generated with the same command that only differ by the two dependencies being arguments in the command. I could write out the four rules I just didn't want to have the command duplicated four times in case I needed to change it in the future.

Comment: Show me the arguments/variables and how you set them?

Comment: When I run the make command I have "REP1=A REP2=B" as arguments. These are data sets that I'm trying to do a consistency analysis with. I create additional data sets from combining the two and then splitting it again (so basically mixing them, which I call AB.pr1 and AB.pr2) and also splitting each individual set into two parts (which I call A.pr1, A.pr2, B.pr1 and B.pr2). The step I'm on now is that I want to create four comparisons between the analysis results of these datasets: A_vs_B, A.pr1_vs_A.pr2, B.pr1_vs_B.pr2, and AB.pr1_vs_AB.pr2.

Comment: Obviously in the makefile I wouldn't use "A" and "B" but "$(REP1)" and "$(REP2)" but it was quicker to write A and B.

Answer (score 2):

Two choices:

1. [Secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) (your idea of string munging in the dependencies). Something like this (might be better/shorter ways but this is what came to me first).

   ```
   A_v_B.txt: $$(addsuffix $$(suffix $$(lastword $$(subst _, ,$$@))),$$(firstword $$(subst _, ,$$@)) $$(lastword $$(basename $$(subst _, ,$$@))))
       @echo $^
   ```
2. Generated targets/prerequisites. Though how you generate the targets/prerequisites you need depends on where/how the pairs are generated/etc.

   ```
   H1 := $(REP1)
   H2 := $(REP2)

   SEP := _vs_
   JOIN := $(SEP)

   define mktgt
       H1 += $R.pr1
       H2 += $R.pr2
       JOIN += $(SEP)
   endef

   $(foreach R,$(REP1) $(REP2) $(REP1)$(REP2),$(eval $(mktgt)))
   PAIRS := $(join $(join $(H1),$(JOIN)),$(H2))
   $(foreach P,$(PAIRS),$(eval $P.txt: $(addsuffix .txt,$(subst _vs_, ,$P))))

   # Debugging output
   $(foreach P,$(PAIRS),$(info $P.txt: $(addsuffix .txt,$(subst _vs_, ,$P))))
   ```

   That creates (as you'll see from the debugging output) the target/prerequisite mappings. It doesn't give the targets any recipe. I assume you have a recipe already and that you've assigned it to all the appropriate targets.

   If not then adding something like:

   ```
   $(PAIRS):
           @echo 'Use $^ to generate $@'
   ```

   should work.