# Parametrize Makefile Targets

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have a parameter space, say A={1,2}, B={u,v}, and I need to create a file for each pair `(a,b)` in `A x B`.
What I need generated is a set of Makefile targets such as:

```
file_1_u.csv:
    ./run_program --A 1 --B u > file_1_u.csv
file_1_v.csv:
    ./my_program --A 1 --B v > file_1_u.csv
file_2_u.csv:
    ./run_program --A 2 --B u > file_1_u.csv
file_2_v.csv:
    ./my_program --A 2 --B v > file_1_u.csv
```

Is it possible to generate the targets *and* use the pertaining parameters in each generated target?

PS.:
I know that targets can be created by using variables, but then `$@` only gives only the full target name (e.g. `file_1_u.csv`). Instead, I need `a` and `b` individually to pass them as arguments to `my_program`.

Comment: Does my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33156456/258523) help here?

Comment: Can't you use use $* and a pattern rule? section 4.12.1 of the manual describes static pattern rules. Section 10.5.3 automatic variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, handling more than 1 element in the pattern in a makefile require eval, $$, includes and other non-straightforward processing.

However, in your specific example there is an obvious substitution that could be used like this:

```
A:=1 2
B:=u v
l:=$(foreach a, $(A), $(foreach b, $(B), $(a)_$(b)))

all: $(l:%=file_%.csv)

file_%.csv:
        ./run_program --A $(subst _, --B ,$*) > $@
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I accepted it since yours is the shortest solution, but @andrey-starodubtsev's answer works as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need something like this:

```
define foo
test_$(1)_$(2) :
  ./my_program --A $(1) --B $(2) > file_$(1)_$(2).csv
endef

a=1 2
b=u v
$(foreach a_,$(a),$(foreach b_,$(b),$(eval $(call foo,$(a_),$(b_)))))
```

Comment: As an added bonus this solution would give you extra job security, because almost no one else would know what the Makefile does, let alone be able to maintain it...     (sorry, couldn't resist :-)

Comment: As an extra job security without loosing maintainability of your code you can always use encrypted comments =)